# Is my ebike drive train actually broken ? BOSCH error code 500

Tags: electric-bike

My aunts ebike has just reached 992 km.
The bike has an bosch active line ebike motor and the display shows **error code 500**.
Which apparently means it's broken.
That would be terrible in my opinion without reaching even 1000 km.
I checked the magnets and cables and everything seems fine.

- Do I miss something here? Can I hard reset the bike somehow ?
- Should I buy a device to read the error code or update the bike ?
- Is the drive train / motor actually broken and should I buy a new one ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: The description for error code is 500 - "Internal error in the drive unit Restart the system. If the problem persists, contact your Bosch eBike dealer." I think you're limited in your options, it needs the Bosch diagnostic tool to diagnose and clear the error. It may be a warranty issue, it hasn't reached any reasonable life span.

Comment: Warranty is overdue... already tried that and the eBike dealer wants so much money my aunt could almost by a new bike for that. I want to save that bike before it gets replaced. My options are saving the bike myself. Restart doesnt work. If the the motor is broken I can buy one online and replace it but do I actually have to ?
Or maybe check the motor from inside and see whats broken.

Comment: I've opened up a Yamaha/ Giant e-bike motor and repaired a worn bushing. It wasn't easy but it was doable. However, I think this is unlikely to be a mechanical problem and more likely a PCB issue. I would keep arguing for replacement. Not sure of consumer rights in your country, but I would definitely argue that the bike has failed prematurely regardless of the warranty period. (I know in a number of countries retailers have a responsibility to ensure the good lasts the expected lifetime, not just the warranty period). I'd also contact Corratec and Bosch and see what they have to say.

Comment: @DWGKNZ these are all answers.  Please put them in the answers box so you can earn useful reputation from upvotes.   Votes on comments do not earn rep.

Comment: @Criggie, IMHO there isn't an answer there, just suggestions at this point. I can't definitively give an answer. (I gave up on chasing rep many years ago)